# Persisting run configuration when running tests from IntelliJ gutter

Tags: intellij-idea, mocha.js

I want to run JavaScript tests from the IntelliJ gutter (the green double-arrow icons on the left side, by the line numbers).

I've set up a Run/Debug configuration for Mocha that works fine when it's used to run all my unit tests at once.
Its Node interpreter is the project's, at v8.11.4.
Its Node options are empty.
Its working directory is `my/project/src`.
Its environment variable is `BABEL_ENV=test`.
Its Mocha package is `my/project/src/node_modules/mocha`.
Its UI is `mocha-when-then`.
Its extra Mocha options are `--compilers js:babel-core/register --require babel-polyfill --require ./testSetup.js --require ignore-styles`.
Its test directory is `my/project/src/test/`, set to "All in directory".

Everything works fine when running the main, all-tests configuration. But when I run an individual test or test suite from the gutter, I get errors, because IntelliJ generates a new configuration with default settings, like blank fields for Mocha options and environment variables. I can work around this by manually copying the settings over, but having to do that for every single run is a huge waste of time.

My co-workers don't have this problem even though their configuration is identical to mine. (Identical in the IntelliJ Run/Debug Configurations menu, anyways. Obviously, *something* is different between our setups.)

How can I make the project settings apply or persist to tests that I run from the gutter?

Comment: You could edit Run configuration template under "Run Configurations | Templates". So generated run configuration will already have all needed fields.